# Access array within Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an http request that calls an api and returns something that looks like this in the body. I need to access the "members" array. `body.results` is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

The call to get this data looks like this:

```
http.get(options, function(error, response, body)
```

Results below:

```
{ results: [ { members: [Array] } ],
  performanceStats:
   { inspectedCount: 2213,
     omittedCount: 0,
     matchCount: 828,
     wallClockTime: 101 },
  metadata:
   { eventTypes: [ 'SomeType' ],
     eventType: 'SomeType',
     openEnded: true,
     beginTime: '2020-01-06T10:36:48Z',
     endTime: '2020-01-07T10:36:48Z',
     beginTimeMillis: 1578307008262,
     endTimeMillis: 1578393408262,
     rawSince: '1 DAYS AGO',
     rawUntil: 'NOW',
     rawCompareWith: '',
     guid: '728c90b2-9637-cd72-26b3-8e05a6fa6fba',
     routerGuid: '969d2d3a-e77c-db66-9a4a-c0141a516404',
     messages: [],
     contents: [ [Object] ] } }
```

Comment: Could you please add a code that calls the endpoint so that we could see what `body` is?

Comment: Can you show the process of ending up with this var/const of `body`, otherwise it's really difficult to tell what you're doing wrong? If you include that code in your question it would be helpful.

Comment: The result is probably not parsed as JSON, so `body` may just be a string that contains the JSON. Maybe try `const bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);` and then check if `bodyParsed.results` is the array

Comment: `results` is an array  so members is at 0th index. try `body.results[0]`

Comment: If you share the piece of code then it will help us in resolving it better. One thing you can try is using `async await` or `callback` since network requests are asynchronous. If you are not waiting for the response to come then you will get `undefined`.

Comment: @Mridul body.results[0] worked. You should post that as the answer.

Comment: @JimmyD i added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > JSON Response

```
{ results: [ { members: [Array] } ],
 performanceStats:
 { inspectedCount: 2213,
 omittedCount: 0,
 matchCount: 828,
 wallClockTime: 101 },
 metadata:
 { eventTypes: [ 'SomeType' ],
 eventType: 'SomeType',
 openEnded: true,
 beginTime: '2020-01-06T10:36:48Z',
 endTime: '2020-01-07T10:36:48Z',
 beginTimeMillis: 1578307008262,
 endTimeMillis: 1578393408262,
 rawSince: '1 DAYS AGO',
 rawUntil: 'NOW',
 rawCompareWith: '',
 guid: '728c90b2-9637-cd72-26b3-8e05a6fa6fba',
 routerGuid: '969d2d3a-e77c-db66-9a4a-c0141a516404',
 messages: [],
 contents: [ [Object] ] } }
```

To access `members`

```
body.results[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let c = { results: [ { members: [2,3] } ],
  performanceStats:
   { inspectedCount: 2213,
     omittedCount: 0,
     matchCount: 828,
     wallClockTime: 101 },
  metadata:
   { eventTypes: [ 'SomeType' ],
     eventType: 'SomeType',
     openEnded: true,
     beginTime: '2020-01-06T10:36:48Z',
     endTime: '2020-01-07T10:36:48Z',
     beginTimeMillis: 1578307008262,
     endTimeMillis: 1578393408262,
     rawSince: '1 DAYS AGO',
     rawUntil: 'NOW',
     rawCompareWith: '',
     guid: '728c90b2-9637-cd72-26b3-8e05a6fa6fba',
     routerGuid: '969d2d3a-e77c-db66-9a4a-c0141a516404',
     messages: [],
     contents: [ [Object] ] } }

console.log(c.results[0].members)
```

I keep ur response to variable `c`
Then first i call the `c` then call the `results`
after that there is one object only so i use `[0]`
then call the `members`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the response body as response.data.results